# how to create a collection of array type variable with somepart of variable names similar and other part is incrementing?

Tags: php

I want to make 10 variables with name as answer-1,answer-2,answer-3 and so on. Can i use for loop in such a manner to create variables, if not then how can i do it?

```
<?php
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
$answer_+i=new array();
}
?>
```

Comment: That is known as [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). But 99% of the time, you should leave that "feature" alone and use a multidimensional array instead. (Also, it's simply `= array()`, not `= new array()`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP syntax is all wrong (Yes you missed some `$`s and added extra `new`). You can create them using following syntax. Its called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    ${"answer_$i"} = array();
}
```

But I suggest you use array for this. Array is more convenient.

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    $answer[$i] = array();
}
```

Here your `$answer_1` will be `$answer[1]`. Best is to use no explicit index

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    $answer[] = array();
}
```

Now `$answer_1` will be `$answer[0]`. You can loop over it by `for`, `foreach`, can use a lot of [array functions](http://php.net/array).

Comment: Can i do this way <?php
$correct=0;
$i=1;
while($i<=10) {
$answer="answer_".$i;
echo $answer."<br/>";
echo "$_POST[$answer]";
$i++;
}

Comment: Yes. that'll just set answer_1, answer_2 ... keys to `$_POST`

Comment: while($i<=10) {

$answer="answer-".$i;
${"answer-$i"}=$_POST[$answer];
$i++;
}                                                                  Is this possible? I am doubtfull about ${"answer-$i"}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as stated in another answer, but usually the following is suited better:

```
<?php
$answers = array();
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
$answers[]= array("blah", "123");
}
?>
```

So you can access answer #4 with:

```
<?php
$answers = array();
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
$answers[]= array("blah", $i);
}
echo $answers[3] //array indexes start at 0!
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a multidimensional array like:

```
$answers = array(
  1 => array(),
  2 => array()
);
```

... or ...

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
  $answers[$i] = array();
```